# Get entire page into container and hide/show it without reloading

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom-manipulation

I want to load full pages somewhere into DOM and 
keep them inside its own "containers" for showing and hiding.

So far i tried:
1) Loading page into div but some things like background image and css are getting
out of the "container" even if its hidden like this:

```
    $("#page" + index).hide().load(url);
```

2) If i will load it into :

```
    $("#page" + index).html('<object data="' + url + '">');
```

it keeps page inside of container but when i use jQuery show/hide it reloads every time.

I haven't tried iframes but with the framebreakers i guess some page would take over the screen.

Do you have any idea how to do it?

Answer (score 0):

Does the url you're loading contain an extra set of html, head or body tags? Html documents should only contain one set of these.

Comment: Yes,It does contains own html etc. tags.

Answer (score 0):

You probably don't want to load entire documents (with all header/body information etc), into elements of another document; thats going to be difficult to work with.

You could use jQuery.load with the a filter to only load elements of a certain class, i.e. put one big div around the content that you actually want to pull in, and then use that to filter to jquery load.

> **Loading Page Fragments**
>
> The .load() method, unlike $.get(), allows us to specify a portion of
>   the remote document to be inserted. This is achieved with a special
>   syntax for the url parameter. If one or more space characters are
>   included in the string, the portion of the string following the first
>   space is assumed to be a jQuery selector that determines the content
>   to be loaded.
>
> We could modify the example above to use only part of the document
>   that is fetched:
>
> $( "#result" ).load( "ajax/test.html #container" ); When this method
>   executes, it retrieves the content of ajax/test.html, but then jQuery
>   parses the returned document to find the element with an ID of
>   container. This element, along with its contents, is inserted into the
>   element with an ID of result, and the rest of the retrieved document
>   is discarded.
>
> jQuery uses the browser's .innerHTML property to parse the retrieved
>   document and insert it into the current document. During this process,
>   browsers often filter elements from the document such as ,
>   , or  elements. As a result, the elements retrieved by
>   .load() may not be exactly the same as if the document were retrieved
>   directly by the browser.

From here:

http://api.jquery.com/load/